# PHP: Json encode addslashes only to a specific value

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP array as follows:

```
Array
(
    [Caller] => EFLwebsite
    [CaseDetails] => Array
        (
            [Description] => This is a Site Readiness case.
            [SAPCustomerCode] => 1001140090
            [ProductNumber] => GWPDREVIV00000
            [CustomerAssetSerialNumber] => 000000000418005207
            [RequestedDate] => 2021/01/06
            [RequestedTime] => 10:00:45
            [BP] => CRM Test User
        )

)
```

I need to convert the above array into json as follows:

```
{
    "Caller":"EFLwebsite",
    "CaseDetails":"{\"Description\":\"This is a Site Readiness case.\",\"SAPCustomerCode\":\"0100301500\",\"ProductNumber\":\"GWPDFCOND00000\",\"CustomerAssetSerialNumber\":\"000000000418005207\",\"RequestedDate\":\"2021\/01\/06\",\"RequestedTime\":\"23:54:12\",\"BP\":\"CRM Test User\"}"
}
```

I am using addslases() after json_encode but it returns as follows:

```
{
    \"Caller\":\"EFLwebsite\",
    \"CaseDetails\":{\"Description\":\"This is a Site Readiness case.\",\"SAPCustomerCode\":\"1001140090\",\"ProductNumber\":\"GWPDREVIV00000\",\"CustomerAssetSerialNumber\":\"000000000418005207\",\"RequestedDate\":\"2021\\/01\\/06\",\"RequestedTime\":\"10:00:45\",\"BP\":\"CRM Test User\"}
}
```

I need to add the slashes only to the second value which is CaseDetails
I also tried encoding the subarray separately and adding slashes as a string, but it is adding more slashes again.

Comment: Is there any good reason to do this? Why not trust that `json_encode` works properly?

Comment: The api is not accepting any other format
[message] => An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An unexpected 'StartObject' node was found for property named 'CaseDetails' when reading from the JSON reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have no idea why you would want to do this, but this should do the trick:

```
$array = [
    "Caller"  => "EFLwebsite",
    "CaseDetails" => [
            "Description" => "This is a Site Readiness case.",
            "SAPCustomerCode" => "1001140090"
        ]

];

// first convert case details to json 
$array["CaseDetails"] = json_encode($array["CaseDetails"]);

echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_encode($array)); // then convert everything to json
echo "</pre>";
```

This returns:

```
{"Caller":"EFLwebsite",
 "CaseDetails":"{\"Description\":\"This is a Site Readiness case.\",\"SAPCustomerCode\":\"1001140090\"}"}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Its a weird requirement in the API input as it is not accepting the JSON string without the slashes

Comment: @SufyanKhot Yes, it's not how it should be: json within json is weird.

Answer (score 1):

Using heredoc string with php. [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> Heredoc text behaves just like a double-quoted string, without the double quotes. This means that quotes in a heredoc do not need to be escaped, but the escape codes listed above can still be used. Variables are expanded, but the same care must be taken when expressing complex variables inside a heredoc as with strings.

```
$case = addslases(json_encode($array['CaseDetails']));
$json = <<<EOT
{ "Caller": "{$array['Caller']}", "CaseDetails": {$case} }
EOT;
echo $json;
```